# if elif(conditions) in Jython FDMEE keeps giving wrong result

Tags: jython

it shall be a simple if elif(conditions) in jython, but it seems like Jython in FDMEE keeps checking for wrong result in the condition.

```
def Timetest(strField, strRecord):  
    import java.util.Date as date  
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat as Sdf  
    import java.lang.Exception as Ex   
    import java.sql as sql  
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit as TimeUnit  


    PerKey = fdmContext["PERIODKEY"]  
    strDate = strRecord.split(",")[11]  

    #get maturity date  
    strMM = strDate.split("/")[0]  
    strDD = strDate.split("/")[1]  
    strYYYY = strDate.split("/")[2]  
    strDate = ("%s.%s.%s" % (strMM,strDD, strYYYY))  
    #converting Maturity date   
    sdf = Sdf("MM.dd.yyyy")  
    strMRD = sdf.parse(strDate)  
    #calc date diff  
    diff = (strMRD.getTime()- PerKey.getTime())/86400000  
    diff = ("%d" % diff)  
    if diff>="0":  
        if diff <= "30":  
            return  "Mat_Up1m " + diff  
    elif diff <= "90":  
        return "Mat_1to3m " + diff #the result goes here all the time although my diff is 367  
    elif diff <= "360":  
        return  "Mat_3to12m " + diff   
    elif diff <= "1800":  
        return "Mat_1to5y " + diff  #the result supposed to go here  
    else:  
        return  "Mat_Over5y "+ diff
```

Not sure why it keeps going to the second elif instead of the fourth elif.

My calculation result of diff = 367

any idea on how to make sure that my code read the correct if elif condition?

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have already figured it out, If not then check the mistakes you have made in your script.

- In your script you're comparing string "367" with string values "0","90" etc., its not `integer comparison`, string "367" is always less than string "90" so its going into that elif condition.
- Now you have to do `integer comparison instead of string comparison` and also move your all `elif` conditions inside the main if condition.
- In the return statement you have to convert the `interger to string` to concatinate diff to a string.

Check the following code, with all the changes.

```
if diff>=0:  
    if diff <= 30:  
        return  "Mat_Up1m " + str(diff)  
    elif diff <= 90:  
        return "Mat_1to3m " + str(diff)  
    elif diff <= 360:  
        return  "Mat_3to12m " + str(diff)   
    elif diff <= 1800:  
        return "Mat_1to5y " + str(diff)
    else:
        return  "Mat_Over5y "+ str(diff)
```